# Mat Autocomplete DisplayWith Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I want to achieved to get the itemDescription but the value is id. but the problem is once i selected the specific list in the text it gives me the id instead of the itemDescription how to achieve that also i once i selected the list i got the error of `ERROR TypeError: enterData.toLowerCase is not a function`

```
filteredOptions:any;
options = [];



this.form = this.fb.group({
      id:[0],
      Name:[],
      ArrayForm:this.fb.array([this.CreateArray()])
    })

CreateArray(){
    return this.fb.group({
        item:['']
    })
  }

ngOninit{
this.ArrayForm.get('item').valueChanges.subscribe(response => {
      console.log('data is ', response);
      this.filterData(response);
    })
}

filterData(enterData){
    this.filteredOptions = this.options.filter(item => {
      return item.itemDescription.toLowerCase().indexOf(enterData.toLowerCase()) > -1
    })
  }

getData(){
  this.services.dataList(true).subscribe((response) => {
    this.options = response;
    this.filteredOptions = response;
    console.log(response)
  })
}
```

Here's my services where i map the items of my list and get the specific data

```
dataList(isActive: Boolean){
        let params = new HttpParams();
        params = params.append('isActive', String(isActive));
        return this.http.get(this.appsetting.baseURL + 'myList/list',{params})
        .pipe(
          map((response:any) => response.items.map(items =>items))
        );
      }
```

HTML

```
<td>
    <input matInput type="text" [matAutocomplete]="auto" formControlName="item">
    <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete">
     <mat-option *ngFor="let item of filteredOptions" [value]="item.id">
         {{item.itemDescription}}
     </mat-option>
    </mat-autocomplete>
```

Comment: The second half of the question is unclear to me. Try adding a question mark before calling toLowerCase. It is possible that TS does not know if the value is there. If it is null or undefined then this function cannot be called on such an object. Just like: enterData?.toLowerCase

Comment: @SparrowVic i know the error now it should be [value]="item.itemDescription" needed but i want my value to be id. i try the display it wont show any once i select the data

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, there are two parts to your problem

1. When an Item is selected in `mat-autocomplete`, the value displayed should be
   `itemDescription` instead of `id` correct? It's showing `id` because you are setting the value of option to be `[value]=item.id`. If you want to keep it that way you can use the displayWith property of `mat-autocomplete` to display `itemDescription`

```
  <input matInput type="text" [matAutocomplete]="auto" formControlName="item">
  <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete" [displayWith]="displayDescription">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let item of filteredOptions" [value]="item">
        {{item.itemDescription}}
    </mat-option>
  </mat-autocomplete>
```

and in your typescript component:

```js
  displayDescription: any = (option) => (option ? option.itemDescription: '');
```

2. For your second problem i.e.the error `enterData.toLowerCase is not a function`
   You can filter out the NULL values, or it might be that you are returning the `id` which is a *number* that does not have the `toLowerCase` property

```js
this.ArrayForm.get('item').valueChanges
.pipe( 
      filter(resp=>!resp)
).subscribe(response => {
      console.log('data is ', response);
      this.filterData(response);
    })
}
```

Comment: still no display even i put the displaywith

Comment: @Alluring try to console.log(option) in `displayWith` function and check what's logging.